# Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance in Flatlist React Native

Tags: javascript, api, react-native, object, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to do a infinite scroll loading with flatlist, such like instagram and twitter. Found a view on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WcGd8VkRc48 which works perfectly with this api and functions. I applied my logic to the same api and worked. But when I apply it to my API it gives me the error 'invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance'

So, here is the deal. The componentDidMount() does the fetch perfectly and works great. Now flatlist come with the options on refreshing the whole list or to keep loading later posts such as we do in instagram and timeline apps.

The refresh the whole list, which is the swipe down works perfect. But when I reach the end of the list, I call a function that loads the next items, but in this moment the error appears. It has to be something with the array of objects, but the video earlier works perfect in the same way! Please HELP

```
state = {
        isLoading: true,
        refreshing:false,
        page:0,
        loading: false,
        data:[],
        photoLoading: false,
        photoLoading2: false,
  };

renderItem = ({item}, i) => {'this render item works and has no problem}

_onRefresh = async () =>{
    this.setState({refreshing: true});
    const tk = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
    console.log(tk);
    fetch('MY API LINK /?skip=0&limit=5', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers:{
            'Content-type':'application/json',
            'x-access-token': tk
        }
    })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            if(responseJson.status === 'success'){
                console.log(responseJson);
                this.setState(state => ({
                    data: responseJson.data,
                    refreshing: false
                }));
                console.log('PRINT SUCCESS RESULT OF REFRESH')
                console.log(this.state.data)
            }
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
            console.log('ERROR IN REFRESHING');
            console.log(error)
        })

};

componentDidMount = async () => {    
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    const tk = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
    fetch('MY API LINK /?skip=0&limit=5', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers:{
            'Content-type':'application/json',
            'x-access-token': tk
        }
    })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            console.log(responseJson);
            this.setState(state => ({
                data: responseJson.data,
                isLoading: false,
                refreshing: false
            }));
            console.log('PRINT RESULT')
            console.log(this.state.data)
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
            console.log('ERROR');
            console.log(error)
        })
    // this.fetchData()
}

fetchData = async ()=>{
    this.setState({loading: true})
    const tk = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
    fetch(`MY API LINK /?skip=${this.state.page}&limit5`
    , {
        method: 'GET',
        headers:{
            'Content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'x-access-token': tk
        }
    }
    ).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState(state => ({ 
            data: [...state.data, ...responseJson.data], 
            loading: false, 
            // isLoading:false
        }));
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    })
}

handleEnd = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({ page: state.page + 1 }), () => this.fetchData());
};

render() {
    return (
        this.state.isLoading ?
            <View style={{flex:1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <ActivityIndicator size='large' color={'black'} animating/>
            </View>
        :
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
                data={this.state.data}
                refreshControl={
                    <RefreshControl
                        refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
                        onRefresh={this._onRefresh}
                    />
                }
                keyExtractor={(x, i) => i.toString()}
                onEndReached={() => this.handleEnd()}
                onEndReachedThreshold={0}
                ListFooterComponent={() =>
                this.state.loading ? 
                    null
                    : 
                    <ActivityIndicator size="large" animating />
                }
                renderItem={this.renderItem}
            />
        </View>
    );
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the error, in the fetchData function I missed the '=' in the parameter for getting the results I want.

Code works great now! Hope it helps anyone who reads and wants to do infinite scroll usinf FlatList in React Native